# Using get_inline_instances overwrites add permission?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I currently have a bunch of inlines that all inherit from a base Inline Class set up like this:

```
class BaseInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    extra = 0

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

I now want to change my admin so that depending on the user, the inlines change like so:

```
class PartyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      inline1 = [Inline1, Inline2]
      inline2 = [Inline1, Inline2, Inline3]

      def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
          if request.user.is_staff:
               return [inline(self.model, self.admin_site) for inline in self.inline1]
          else:
               return [inline(self.model, self.admin_site) for inline in self.inline2]
```

However, when I do this, the `has_add_permission` no longer works. When I don't use `get_inline_instances`, the user has no ability to add another item and I would like this functionality to stay consistent. Is there any reason this is not carrying over when I use this method?

For the record, `has_delete_permission` remains False which makes the situation even weirder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_inline_instances` is the method that checks the permission. If you want to check for permissions, you either have to call `super().get_inline_instances()`, or you need to replicate the code from the [original function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/bc53af13cbf09b0cbac945426c2d51d0ca52fff3/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L524).

Comment: Good call, but do you have any idea why the has_delete_permission was working?